# How Control Registers are accessed in Linux

Tags: linux, arm, inline-assembly

i have been reading  Linux source code ported on to a propriety platform based on `ARM Cortex -A7 MPCore - NEON Architecture`

The code below shows how a control register of a module is modified up on calling an API

```
drivers\module\module-specific_file.c
static inline void API(....)
{
    if (set)
        __raw_writel(msk, (void *)((u32) (reg) + 0x1000));
    else
    {
        __raw_writel(msk, (void *)((u32) (reg) + 0x2000));
    }
}
```

in the above code `reg` is actually a virtual address and `msk` is a mask lets say `x7FF` and `set` is a parameter passed which conveys request of set/clear

but actually my doubt is how does modifying the control register address is modifying the value to be written to register ... ?? further if i look at the api which is been called it looks like below

```
arch\arm\include\asm\Io.h
static inline void __raw_writel(u32 val, volatile void __iomem *addr)
{
    asm volatile("str %1, %0"
             : "+Qo" (*(volatile u32 __force *)addr)
             : "r" (val));
}
```

if any one have come across this kind of accessing control registers please let me know how actually content of registers are modified by modifying the virtual address.

Comment: The MMU translates CPU virtual addresses to CPU physical addresses according to how the page tables are set up. There's no restriction to only map those physical addresses which correspond to DRAM...

Comment: Thank you all... after digging in to spec data sheet i found that set and clear are two separate registers with a different offsets , so writing a mask  in 0x1000 would modify the set registers and  modifying register 0x2000 would clear the register

Answer (score 0):

As I know, registers are mapped in virtual address space. Have a look at /proc/iomem for example, you'll see mapped registers addresses and what hardware they are belong. The addresses of registers are strictly determined by hardware developers.
Typically, to map register address one should call ioremap function. It returns the address. Often this address is the base address, where the register addresses begin. To write something in register you just need to write the data in this address plus the resister offset.
E.g.: On ARM PXA320, there is a set of LCD registers. Somewhere ion driver code one may see - ioremap(BASE_ADDR, SIZE_OF_ADDR_SET);
In order to write __raw_write(value, base_addr + offset) function is used.

Comment: yes i do know that and i refereed the same in my question too, as in Linux you cannot write directly to the physical address so we convert our physical addresses to virtual address and use the functions like __raw_write to write values to those registers, even when i have seen some code of other controllers in Linux tree i observed the value is modified and written , but contrary in my case address is modified instead of value i dont understand why so